# ImportantForAccessibility=false vs. ContentDescription=null

Tags: android, accessibility, content-disposition, talkback

There is an element I want TalkBack to skip when reading out lout the screen.

I can set it's `contentDescription` to `null`.

I also read about `ImportantForAccessibility:` indicates whether an element is visible or not to the Accessibility API.

Which other APIs are there?

Is it cleaner to use `ImportantForAccessibility=false` over `contentDescription=null`?

Answer (score 4):

`ImportantForAccessibility=false` is used to hide **any** element from the accessibility tree, including buttons, content etc.

`contentDescription=null` is only useful for things like images (there may be other items I can't think of) that you want to hide as otherwise the Accessibility Tree will do it's best to find a suitable name for an item.

A prime example would be an `ImageButton` - if you use `contentDescription=null` then it will announce 'button' and the destination / button text. If you use `ImportantForAccessibility=false`it would hide that item completely from the accessibility tree.

The best analogy I can come up with (if you are familiar with Web Standards) is that `contentDescription` is like an `alt` attribute or `aria-labelledby` attribute and `ImportantForAccessibility=false` is similar to `aria-hidden="true"`.

**One thing I would caution you on** - other than decorative items you should not really be hiding items from the accessibility tree, just be careful that you are not giving a different experience to screen reader users (you didn't specify your use case, just wanted to hammer that point home).

Final thing - try it with `TalkBack`, testing it on a device is the quickest way to know if you got it right!